# Can't Find What is Creating This Border, Driving Me Crazy?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, border

I have a border around my toggle images and I can't figure out for the life of my why - this is with a custom options panel based on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

See the attached image: [image]

In my functions, how it is being created with markup

```
<div class="rm_section">
<div class="rm_title">
<h3><img class="inactive" alt="">
<?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3><span class="submit"><input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
</span><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="rm_options">
```

MY CSS

```
.rm_wrap{
    width:740px;
}

.rm_section{

}

.rm_opts label{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    color:#444
}
.rm_input {
    padding:30px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    margin:8px 0 0;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px
}
.rm_opts small{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    color:#999
}
.rm_opts input[type="text"], .rm_opts select{
    width:280px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px;
    color:#333;
    line-height:1em;
    background:#f3f3f3;
}
.rm_input input:focus, .rm_input textarea:focus{
        background:#fff;
}
.rm_input textarea{
    width:280px;
    height:175px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px;
    color:#333;
    line-height:1.5em;
    background:#f3f3f3;
}
.rm_title h3 {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:17px 0 0;
    color:#333;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0 4px;
}
.rm_title{
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#eee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #DDD;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px
    }

.rm_title h3 img.inactive{
    margin:-7px 10px 0 5px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;    
    background:url('images/pointer.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
    border:none!important
}

.rm_title h3 img.active{
    margin:-7px 10px 0 5px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;    
    background:url('images/pointer.png') no-repeat  0 -32px;
    float:left;
    border:none!important
}

.rm_title h3:hover img{
    border:none
}

.rm_title span.submit{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:15%;
    padding:14px 0;
}

.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}

.rm_table th, .rm_table td{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.rm_table th, .rm_table td.feature{
    border-color:#888;
    }
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.rm_options').slideUp();

        jQuery('.rm_section h3').click(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).parent().next('.rm_options').css('display')==='none')
                {   jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').children('img').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

                }
            else
                {   jQuery(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').children('img').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
                }

            jQuery(this).parent().next('.rm_options').slideToggle('slow');
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a live page containing the issue?

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you want to remove all borders? Just remove every entry mentioning border in your css?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I can't because it's in my admin panel.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I thought that is what it is too, but CSS isn't causing this border.

Comment: @Lucas Yes it is. CSS is responsible for all presentation of HTML elements. If you have a border, it must be defined in CSS somewhere. You can inspect the element in question in the dev tools of your browser. That will list all CSS that applies to the element.

Comment: @LucasWynne Do as suggested. Install Firefix (if you don't have it), install the plugin called Firebug (google it). Restart browser, right-click on the image with the border, look for the border-attribute in the right-panel. You should find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you won't want borders around your images, so try setting the border width for images explicitly like this:

```
img { border:0px; }
```

In cases where you do want a border around your images, just override the above.

**EDIT**

I see that you have some classes for images specified already in your stylesheet. Instead of setting the border-style to `none`, try setting the border width to `0`. I would also add a space before using `!important`

Comment: not quite true, some browsers have something along the lines of `a img { border: 2px solid blue; }` in their default stylesheet, but I don't know of any that add a border by default.

Comment: Yes, I changed my wording to be a little less assuming. It does look like a default image border might be the culprit in his case though.